# User Segmentation Engine using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filtering, analytics, rule-engine

I have an analytics system that tracks customers and their attributes as well as their behavior in the form of events. It is implemented using Node.js and MongoDB (with Mongoose).

Now I need to implement a segmentation feature that allows to group stored users into segments based on certain conditions. For example something like `purchases > 3 AND country = 'Netherlands'`

In the frontend this would look something like this:

[image]

**An important requirement here is that the segments get updated in realtime and not just periodically.** This basically means, that every time a user's attributes change or he triggers a new event, I have to check again which segments he does belong to.

My current approach is to store the conditions for the segments as MongoDB queries, that I can then execute on the user collection in order to determine which users belong to a certain segment.

For example a segment to filter out all users that are using Gmail would look like this:

```
{
    _id: '591638bf833f8c843e4fef24',
    name: 'Gmail Users',
    condition: {'email': { $regex : '.*gmail.*'}}
}
```

When a user matches the condition I would then store that he belongs to the 'Gmail Users' segment directly on the user's document:

```
{
    username: 'john.doe',
    email: 'john.doe@gmail.com',
    segments: ['591638bf833f8c843e4fef24']
}
```

However by doing this, I would have to execute all queries for all segments every time a user's data changes, so I can check if he is part of the segment or not. This feels a bit complicated and cumbersome from a performance point of view.

**Can you think of any alternative way to approach this?** Maybe use a rule-engine and do the processing in the application and not on the database?

Comment: you're already storing the query in the segment collection, why not also store the field or fields that affect whether or not the user is in the segment?  when user's data changes, you *know* which fields are changing, just compare the fields to the segments - i.e. go in the opposite direction than you are now.

Comment: btw, this is not "real time" - the only way you can get "real time" results is if you simply make the segmentation query each time there's a request in the UI.

Comment: @benjiman i am doing something similar... will you please tell me how to make a page like condition maker ... i mean select filter and their operators with value ... any open source project like your screen shot? i am working in PHP and JS with MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know a better approach but you can optimize this solution a little bit.

I would do the same:

- Store the segment conditions in a collection
- Once you find a matching user, store the segment id in the user's document (`segments`)

> An important requirement here is that the segments get updated in realtime and not just periodically.

You have no choice, you need to run the segmentation query every times when a segment changes.

> I would have to execute all queries for all segments every time a user's data changes

This is where I would change your solution, actually just optimise it a little bit:

- You don't need to run the segmentation queries on the whole collection. If you put your user id into the query with an `$and`, Mongodb will fetch the user first and after that will check the rest of the segmentation conditions. You need to make sure Mongodb uses the user's _id as an index, for this you can use [`.explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) to check it or [`.hint()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) to force it. Unfortunately you need to run N+1 queries if you have N segments (+1 is for the user update)
- I would fetch every segments and store them in a cache (redis). If someone changed the segment I would update the cache as well. (Or just invalidate the cache and the next query will handle the rest, depends on the implementation). The point is that I would have every segments without fetching the database and if a user updated a record I would go through every segments with Node.js and validate the user by the conditions and I could update the user's `segments` array in the original update query so it would not require any extra database operation.
  I know it could be a pain in the ass implementing something like this but it doesn't overload the database ...

**Update**

Let me give you some technical details about my second suggestion: 
*(This is just a pseudo code!)*

Segment cache

```
module.exporst = function() {
  return new Promise(resolve) {
    Redis.get('cache:segments', function(err, segments) {
      // handle error

      // Segments are cached
      if(segments) {
        segments = JSON.parse(segments);
        return resolve(segments);
      }

      //fetch segments and save it to the cache 
      Segments.find().exec(function(err, segments) {
        // handle error

        segments = JSON.stringify(segments);

        // Save to the database but set 60 seconds as an expiration
        Redis.set('cache:segments', segments, 'EX', 60, function(err) {
            // handle error

            return resolve(segments);
        })
      });
    })

   }
}
```

User update

```
// ...    
let user = user.findOne(_id: ObjectId(req.body.userId));
// etc ...

// fetch segments from cache or from the database
let segments = yield segmentCache();

let userSegments = [];
segments.forEach(function(segment) {
  if(checkSegment(user, segment)) {
    userSegments.push(segment._id)
  }
});

// Override user's segments with userSegments
```

This is where the magic happens, somehow you need to define the conditions in a way you can use them in an if statement.

Hint: Lodash has this functions: _.gt, _.gte, _.eq ...

Check segments

```
module.exports = function(user, segment) {
  let keys = Object.keys(segment.condition);
  keys.forEach(function(key) {                
    if(user[key] === segment.condition[key]) {
      return false;
    } 
  }) 

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The idea with the $and query is definitely a good optimization idea. Regarding the caching of the segments I am wondering how you would re-compute the segments in the cache? How would you check if a users is part of a segment or not. Do you mean to run the query on redis or in the app using node.js?

Comment: @benjiman You're welcome. Haha, that's why I wrote it's a pain in the ass because the implementation is not trivial. I will update my answer later on today with some details.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man! I am currently traveling but I will take a closer look tomorrow and message you back :)

Comment: this won't work when user needs to be added to a new segment as a result of the change (but not taken out of an existing segment).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky It will work, you just need to make sure you manage the segment cache right. Invalidate the cache if anything is change related to the segments: crete, update or delete

Comment: FYI: In order to do the matching on the condition I found https://github.com/crcn/sift.js super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are already storing an entire segment "query" in a document in segments collection - why not include a field in the same document which will enumerate which fields in the users document impact membership in a particular segment.

Since action of changing user data will know which fields are being changed, it can fetch only the segments which are computed using the fields being changed significantly reducing the size of segmentation "queries" you have to re-run.

Note that a change in user's data may add them to a segment they are not currently a member of, so checking only the segments currently stored in the user is not sufficient.